# Как преобразовать хеш в цифровое значение

Tags: python, хеширование

Я нахожу хеш изображения

```
hash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('cat4.jpg'))
```

Получается число

```
04068e3b3ccc5f1f
```

Как из него сделать 16-ное представление. Чтобы получилось

```
0x04068e3b3ccc5f1f
```

Comment: это __уже__ 16-ое представление числа. Может вам просто добавить `"0x"` спереди?

Comment: Я пробовал. Но потом проблемы при запись в БД. В бд у меня поле типа bigint. Получается мне нужно не строковое представление, а числовое.

Comment: В Python целые числа всегда представлены в десятичной форме: `hash_int = int(hash, 16)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения числа в формате `BIGINT` вам придется преобразовать хеш в целое число.

Пример:

```
hash = "04068e3b3ccc5f1f"
hash_int = int(hash, 16)
print(hash_int)
# 290075611086216991
```

проверка:

```
print(hex(hash_int))
# 0x4068e3b3ccc5f1f
```